# AJAX call in rails app firing 2 actions

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

The following coffee script

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#tipoarticolos_select', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_articolos',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        tipoarticolo_id: $("#tipoarticolos_select option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic articolo select OK!")
```

is returning the desired behaviour, browser-wise.  However the console is showing two actions being fired `get_articolos`and `update_articolos` in sequence. The route is defined as

```
get 'pickarticolo/update_articolos', as: 'update_articolos'
```

The first fails for - as first reason - lack of route.

```
Started GET "/pickarticolo/get_articolos?tipoarticolo_id=11&_=1481446243515" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-11 09:53:05 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/pickarticolo/get_articolos"):
```

Then the second action fires and runs

```
Started GET "/pickarticolo/update_articolos?tipoarticolo_id=11&_=1481446243516" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-11 09:53:05 +0100
Processing by PickarticoloController#update_articolos as JS
```

I do not understand where the first action is being invoked.  It should be eliminated even though the functionality is proper.

Comment: I dont think the bug is in the code you showed ... something is going on elsewhere.

Comment: There are no routes, nor action references with those strings.  I was wondering whether `type: 'GET'` could be a culprit, generating first the get, then the actual ajax action...

Comment: I think the ajax is ok . nothing in your code has get_articolos in it? a link, a redirection, something?

Comment: no routes, but it turns out I had a coffeescript for another controller with the name that had `$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#tipoarticolos_select', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'get_articolos',
` so the same on change event got evaluated, notwithstanding the controller